# text from RichTextCtrl

Tags: wxpython, richtextbox

I want to get the xml string from a rich text control into a string variable (to store in a database). I can save to file and then read it back out as a string, but there must be  a better way (buffer?).

I've tried

```
  buffer = self.rtc.GetBuffer()
```

but how do you get  the string from the buffer?

Can someone please help me. I've searched documentation and examples but can't find what I neeed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a supplementary to the above:

I have saved the xml as desired, but when I read it back I get an error:

```
XML parsing error: 'no element found' at line 1
```

My code is

```
def OnLstStrategyDClick(self,e):
  index=e.GetSelection()
  self.txtStrategyID.SetValue(self.StrategyList[index][0])
  self.txtDescription.SetValue(self.StrategyList[index][1])
  #print self.StrategyList[index][2]

  out = StringIO()
  handler = wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler()
  buffer = self.txtBidStrategy.GetBuffer()
  buffer.AddHandler(handler)
  out.write(self.StrategyList[index][2])
  out.seek(0)
  handler.LoadStream(buffer, out)
  self.txtBidStrategy.Refresh()

  self.txtBidStrategy.SetValue(self.StrategyList[index][2])
```

The xml code looks fine (well, it has been generated by the handler)

Comment: Could you include the XML output? You might also want to put this in your question as it's not really an answer

Comment: I suppose the other question is: what are you reading it back with?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<richtext version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.wxwidgets.org">
  <paragraphlayout textcolor="#4C4C4C" fontsize="11" fontstyle="90" fontweight="90" fontunderlined="0" fontface="Ubuntu" alignment="1" parspacingafter="10" parspacingbefore="0" linespacing="10">
    <paragraph alignment="2">
      <text>sdgfasdgf</text>
    </paragraph>
  </paragraphlayout>
</richtext>

Comment: Mike I've added the lines "root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
        print root.paragraphlayout.paragraph.getchildren()[0]" to my file and get the following error: :
 
    root = objectify.fromstring(self.StrategyList[index][2])
  File "lxml.objectify.pyx", line 1830, in lxml.objectify.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.objectify.c:19353)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2754, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:54631)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1569, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:82659)
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported.

Comment: Unicode strings? You'll have to look into how to decode those. I remember doing that with this module a couple of years ago: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode It worked quite well.

Comment: OK. Thanks Mike. But I'm just decoding the xml that the handler created - wierd

Comment: Yeah, that is weird...unless you entered unicode into your RichTextCtrl widget

Comment: This nis now solved. The trick that I missed was that the SQL command does not necessarily return a string. Once I forced It into a string it's OK

Answer (score 1):

I would use `StringIO` to write the data to and then print it out of that. If you do it this way, then you just write to memory which is a lot faster to read from then disk. I found an [example](http://play.pixelblaster.ro/blog/archive/2008/10/08/richtext-control-with-wxpython-saving-and-loading) that did most of what you wanted, but it had a lot of extra junk in it, so I pared that example down to the following:

```
import wx
import wx.richtext

from StringIO import StringIO


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Richtext Test')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.rt = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(self)
        self.rt.SetMinSize((300,200))

        save_button = wx.Button(self, label="Save")
        save_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_save)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.rt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 6)
        sizer.Add(save_button, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 6)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_save(self, event):
        out = StringIO()
        handler = wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler()
        rt_buffer = self.rt.GetBuffer()
        handler.SaveStream(rt_buffer, out)
        out.seek(0)
        self.xml_content = out.read()
        print self.xml_content


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**UPDATE** - Just for fun, I decided to extend this example by making it write the XML to file and then read it back and parse out whatever text was entered:

```
import wx
import wx.richtext

from lxml import objectify
from StringIO import StringIO


########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Richtext Test')

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.rt = wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl(self)
        self.rt.SetMinSize((300,200))

        save_button = wx.Button(self, label="Save")
        save_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_save)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.rt, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 6)
        sizer.Add(save_button, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 6)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show()


    def on_save(self, event):
        out = StringIO()
        handler = wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler()
        rt_buffer = self.rt.GetBuffer()
        handler.SaveStream(rt_buffer, out)
        out.seek(0)
        self.xml_content = out.read()
        print self.xml_content

        with open("test.xml", "w") as xml_file:
            xml_file.write(self.xml_content)

        self.parse_xml()

    def parse_xml(self):
        '''
        Parse the XML with the lxml module
        '''
        with open("test.xml") as xml_file:
            xml = xml_file.read()

        root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
        print root.paragraphlayout.paragraph.getchildren()[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that the lxml module is not a part of Python, but can be easily acquired [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html)

Here's some example XML I got when I ran this program:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<richtext version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.wxwidgets.org">
  <paragraphlayout textcolor="#3C3C3C" fontsize="10" fontstyle="90" fontweight="90" fontunderlined="0" fontface="Droid Sans" alignment="1"    parspacingafter="10" parspacingbefore="0" linespacing="10">
    <paragraph>
      <text>glgfh</text>
    </paragraph>
  </paragraphlayout>
</richtext>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. That looks exactly like the solution to my problem. I'll try implementing it now